# Python regex for date and numbers, find the date format

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How to extract dates alone from text file using regex in Python 3?

Below is my current code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import re
s = "birthday on 20/12/2018 and wedding aniversry on 04/01/1997 and dob is on 
09/07/1897"
match = re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', s)
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
print (date)
```

Expected Output is

```
20/12/2018
04/01/1997
09/07/1897
```

Comment: You have `'%d/%m/%Y'` date format, see [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zknvl5).

Comment: `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d/%m/%Y').date()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid date format near `'%Y-%m-%d'` since it should have been `'%d/%m/%Y`' looking at your provided date: `birthday on 20/12/2018` `(dd/mm/yyyy)`

**Change this**:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

**With this**:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

**Your Fix**:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import re
s = "birthday on 20/12/2018"
match = re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', s)
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d/%m/%Y').date()
print (date)
```

**But**:

Why get into all the trouble? When they're easier and elegant ways out there.

Using [`dparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
dt_1 = "birthday on 20/12/2018"
print("Date: {}".format(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True).date()))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Date: 2018-12-20
```

**EDIT**:

With your edited question which now has multiple dates, you could extract them using `regex`:

```
import re
s = "birthday on 20/12/2018 and wedding aniversry on 04/01/1997 and dob is on 09/07/1897"
pattern = r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}'
print("\n".join(re.findall(pattern,s)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
20/12/2018
04/01/1997
09/07/1897
```

**OR**

Using `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

for s in s.split():
    try:
        print(parse(s))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
2018-12-20 00:00:00
1997-04-01 00:00:00
1897-09-07 00:00:00
```

Comment: @Python_beginner sure, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Building on DirtyBit's answer. I found that if you make a minor change, it will pick up multiple date formats. Change the forward slash to a dot.

```
import re
s = "birthday on 20.12.2018 and wedding anniversary on 04-01-1997 and dob 
is on 09/07/1897"
pattern = r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}'
print("\n".join(re.findall(pattern,s)))
```

Output

```
20.12.2018
04-01-1997
09/07/1897
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right expect this line,

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

You have to give the same format as your input has in `datetime.strptime`.

```
'%Y-%m-%d' >> 2018-12-20
'%d/%m/%Y' >> 20/12/2018
```

**Edit**

If you are not looking for datetime object. You can do like this

```
results = re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', s)
print('\n'.join(results))
```

Output

```
In [20]: results = re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', s)

In [21]: print('\n'.join(results))
20/12/2018
04/01/1997
09/07/1897
```

Comment: @Python_beginner You are converting to the `datetime` object which has a unique representation.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have made some changes in the code pls see and fix my issue